# Missing FROM clause when joining two tables on a foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to make a view where two tables are joined. Here ps_id in Members is a foreign key referencing Parking_Spots

```
CREATE VIEW admin_db AS
SELECT * FROM public."Members", public."Parking_Spots"
WHERE Parking_Spots.ps_id = Members.ps_id
```

I get this error

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "parking_spots"
LINE 4: WHERE Parking_Spots.ps_id = Members.ps_id
```

Comment: `MyTable = mytable = "mytable" != "MyTable"`. Same for any other DB objects. Avoid double quotes at all if it still possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as enforcing case sensitivity using quotes, I'd suggest using the correct join syntax:

```
CREATE VIEW admin_db
AS
    SELECT  *
      FROM  public."Members" AS m
        INNER JOIN public."Parking_Spots" AS p ON p.ps_id = m.ps_id
```

This eliminates the need to specify the quoted table names in the `WHERE` syntax and is (arguably) a better approach for joining the data.

Comment: Offtopic, but: `ON p.ps_id = m.ps_id` is same to `using (ps_id)`

Comment: @Abelisto Thank you for the note.  That is of course correct, but my preference is to use join syntax that is standard across RDBMS (which `USING(...)` is not)

Comment: I tried this and it did resolve the previous issue, however now a new error pops up saying that ps_id is specified more than once. I thought if it was joined, this wouldnt happen?

Comment: @MikeHoch Provided you are not doing anything extra, I would think that is because with `SELECT *` you are returning the column from both tables.  Better to define your output column list explicitly

Answer (score 3):

Postgres lowercases your identifiers unless you use double quotes.

So `"Parking_Spots"` is different from `Parking_Spots`.

This is why the error message complains about missing `parking_spots` although you typed it differently.

To sum this up: It is less error prone to use lowercase identifiers. Or better: The case you type does not matter if you don't use double quotes.

Comment: I don't agree with the last sentence. You can use any cases but without double quotes.

Comment: Yes, do not use double quotes so that everything ends up lowercase in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes is the pain here.

For example, it is absolutely valid statement:

```
create table "Aa..%#bB:==>"(" 8==⊃" int);
insert into "Aa..%#bB:==>"(" 8==⊃") values(333), (666), (999);
```

However after such silly thing you will be doomed to use double quotes everywhere like

```
select " 8==⊃" from "Aa..%#bB:==>" where " 8==⊃" >= 666;
```

because without quotes it will be erroneous:

```
select  8==⊃ from Aa..%#bB:==> where  8==⊃ >= 666;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=198860efc7a87c9a0d9031ff48a69113)